# Map loading is very slow with too many polygons on the map using Polygon api google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I'm currently using this Google API:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple?hl=en

It works perfectly, but when I have a lot of polygon demarcations, the map loading and navigation is very slow, I did some research that will indicate using the polygon data layer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-polygon?hl=en

But the Data Layer Polygon does not have the same methods as the simple polygon, refactoring I managed to leave it that way, but the demarcations of the polygons do not appear, can you help me on how to improve the loading, or indicate another way for me to be doing this?

code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { computeChanges } from '../../../helpers/google-maps';
import {
  ColorPaletteStateNumber,
  DataPolygon,
  PALETTE,
  Polygon,
  polygonToJstsPolygon,
} from './commons';

export type UseGoogleMapsPolygonsType = {
  readonly dataPolygons: DataPolygon[];
};

export type UseGoogleMapsPolygonsCreateType = {
  mapInstance: google.maps.Map<Element> | null;
  onPolygonClicked?(polygon: Polygon): void;
  polygons?: Polygon[];
};

const getPolygonColor = (polygon: Polygon): string => {
  const palette = polygon.colorPalette
    ? PALETTE[polygon.colorPalette]
    : PALETTE.default;
  if (polygon.highlight) return palette.highlight;
  if (polygon.disabled) return palette.disabled;
  return palette.normal;
};

const getPolygonNumber = (
  polygon: Polygon,
  field: ColorPaletteStateNumber,
): number => {
  const palette = polygon.colorPalette
    ? PALETTE[polygon.colorPalette]
    : PALETTE.default;
  return palette[field];
};

export const useGoogleMapsPolygons = ({
  mapInstance,
  onPolygonClicked,
  polygons,
}: UseGoogleMapsPolygonsCreateType): UseGoogleMapsPolygonsType => {
  const [dataPolygons, setDataPolygons] = useState<DataPolygon[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (polygons) {
      const result = computeChanges<Polygon, DataPolygon>(
        polygons,
        dataPolygons,
      );

      if (result.hasChanges()) {
        const newDataPolygons: DataPolygon[] = [];
        dataPolygons.forEach(dataPolygon => {
          if (result.idsToRemove.includes(dataPolygon.targetId)) {
            dataPolygon.mapPolygon.getArray();
          } else {
            window.google.maps.event.clearListeners(
              dataPolygon.mapPolygon,
              'click',
            );
            if (onPolygonClicked) {
              dataPolygon.mapPolygon.forEachLatLng(() =>
                onPolygonClicked(dataPolygon.data),
              );
            }
            newDataPolygons.push(dataPolygon);
          }
        });

        result.itemsToUpdate.forEach(item => {
          const dataPolygon = dataPolygons.find(
            searchItem => searchItem.targetId === item.id,
          );
          if (dataPolygon) {
            dataPolygon.data = item;
            dataPolygon.lastModified = item.lastModified;
            // dataPolygon.mapPolygon({
            //   paths: item.coordinates,
            //   strokeColor: getPolygonColor(item),
            //   strokeOpacity: getPolygonNumber(item, 'strokeOpacity'),
            //   strokeWeight: 3,
            //   fillColor: getPolygonColor(item),
            //   fillOpacity: getPolygonNumber(item, 'fillOpacity'),
            //   zIndex: 1000,
            // });
            dataPolygon.jstsPolygon = polygonToJstsPolygon(
              dataPolygon.mapPolygon,
            );
            dataPolygon.mapPolygon.getArray();
          }
        });

        result.itemsToAdd.forEach(item => {
          const mapPolygon = new window.google.maps.Data.Polygon([
            item.coordinates,
          ]);

          mapPolygon.getArray();
          if (onPolygonClicked) {
            mapPolygon.forEachLatLng(() => onPolygonClicked(item));
          }
          newDataPolygons.push({
            targetId: item.id,
            lastModified: item.lastModified,
            data: item,
            mapPolygon,
            jstsPolygon: polygonToJstsPolygon(mapPolygon),
          });
        });
        setDataPolygons(newDataPolygons);
      } else {
        dataPolygons.forEach(dataPolygon => {
          window.google.maps.event.clearListeners(
            dataPolygon.mapPolygon,
            'click',
          );
          if (onPolygonClicked) {
            dataPolygon.mapPolygon.forEachLatLng(() =>
              onPolygonClicked(dataPolygon.data),
            );
          }
          dataPolygon.mapPolygon.getArray();
        });
      }
    } else {
      dataPolygons.forEach(dataPolygon => dataPolygon.mapPolygon.getArray());
    }
  }, [polygons, dataPolygons, mapInstance, onPolygonClicked]);

  return {
    dataPolygons,
  };
};
```

Comment: I would suggest to hard refresh the page whilst keeping an eye on the network tab in the dev tools, then you will be able to see what's taking too long and how to improve the performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I have already tried but still no success.